# Allowing Slicers When Using DAX Calculate Measure

Tags: powerbi, dax

I created a calculated measure in DAX to find the number of new clients found in the previous year. In order to do so I created the following measure:

```
ClientsPreviousYear = CALCULATE(DISTINCTCOUNTNOBLANK(Client[ClientID]), SAMEPERIODLASTYEAR('Date'[Date]), ALL(Client))
```

I also have two slicers on my dashboard, Client[Group] and Client[Industry], however my slicers do not filter down the card I created with ClientsPreviousYear. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the measure you've disabled any filters on Client by passing `All(Client)` to the CALCULATE function.

See [CALCULATE - Filter Modifier Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/calculate-function-dax#filter-modifier-functions).

Comment: Thank you, that was very helpful! In case anyone else has the same issue, this is what my measure ended up looking like: ClientsPreviousYear = calculate(Counta(Client[ClientID]), DATESBETWEEN('Date'[Date],STARTOFMONTH(SAMEPERIODLASTYEAR('Date'[Date])), ENDOFMONTH(SAMEPERIODLASTYEAR('Date'[Date]))))